# Saving this Keras model blows up

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Consider the following program:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.linalg import matmul
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

class MinimalRNNCell(tfk.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states=None, constants=None, *args, **kwargs):
        prev_output = states[0]
        print("constants: ", constants[0].name)
        h = matmul(inputs, self.kernel) + constants[0]
        output = h + matmul(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]

    def get_config(self):
        return dict(super().get_config(), **{'units': self.units})

cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
x = tfk.Input((None, 5), name='x')
z = tfk.Input((1,), name='z')
layer = tfk.layers.RNN(cell, name='rnn')
y = layer(x, constants=[z])

model = tfk.Model(inputs=[x, z], outputs=[y])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.predict([np.array([[[0,0,0,0,0]]]), np.array([[0]])])
model.save('tmp.model')
```

Everything works until saving, at which point it blows up:

```
constants:  z:0
constants:  z:0
constants:  constants:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1880, in _create_c_op
    c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 5 for '{{node add/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](MatMul, constants)' with input shapes: [?,32], [?,?,5].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1245, in binary_op_wrapper
    out = r_op(x)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1267, in r_binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1565, in _add_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.add_v2(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 532, in add_v2
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 748, in _apply_op_helper
    op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 599, in _create_op_internal
    return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3557, in _create_op_internal
    ret = Operation(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2041, in __init__
    self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1883, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 5 for '{{node add/add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](MatMul, constants)' with input shapes: [?,32], [?,?,5].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 43, in <module>
    model.save('tmp.model')
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2111, in save
    save.save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer, save_format,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 150, in save_model
    saved_model_save.save(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py", line 89, in save
    saved_nodes, node_paths = save_lib.save_and_return_nodes(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1103, in save_and_return_nodes
    _build_meta_graph(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1290, in _build_meta_graph
    return _build_meta_graph_impl(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1207, in _build_meta_graph_impl
    signatures = signature_serialization.find_function_to_export(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/signature_serialization.py", line 99, in find_function_to_export
    functions = saveable_view.list_functions(saveable_view.root)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 154, in list_functions
    obj_functions = obj._list_functions_for_serialization(  # pylint: disable=protected-access  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2713, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    functions = super(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 3016, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    return (self._trackable_saved_model_saver
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/base_serialization.py", line 92, in list_functions_for_serialization
    fns = self.functions_to_serialize(serialization_cache)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 73, in functions_to_serialize
    return (self._get_serialized_attributes(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 89, in _get_serialized_attributes
    object_dict, function_dict = self._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/model_serialization.py", line 53, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    super(ModelSavedModelSaver, self)._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 99, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 154, in wrap_layer_functions
    original_fns = _replace_child_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 284, in _replace_child_layer_functions
    child_layer._trackable_saved_model_saver._get_serialized_attributes(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 89, in _get_serialized_attributes
    object_dict, function_dict = self._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 151, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    super(RNNSavedModelSaver, self)._get_serialized_attributes_internal(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 99, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 204, in wrap_layer_functions
    fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 120, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 367, in tracing_scope
    fn.get_concrete_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1367, in get_concrete_function
    concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1273, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 599, in wrapper
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 165, in wrap_with_training_arg
    return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py", line 109, in smart_cond
    return smart_module.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py", line 56, in smart_cond
    return false_fn()
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 163, in replace_training_and_call
    return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 681, in call
    return call_and_return_conditional_losses(inputs, *args, **kwargs)[0]
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 639, in __call__
    return self.wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 599, in wrapper
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 165, in wrap_with_training_arg
    return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py", line 109, in smart_cond
    return smart_module.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py", line 56, in smart_cond
    return false_fn()
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 163, in replace_training_and_call
    return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 663, in call_and_return_conditional_losses
    call_output = layer_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 802, in call
    last_output, outputs, states = backend.rnn(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 4377, in rnn
    output_time_zero, _ = step_function(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 789, in step
    output, new_states = cell_call_fn(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1030, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 69, in return_outputs_and_add_losses
    outputs, losses = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 165, in wrap_with_training_arg
    return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py", line 109, in smart_cond
    return smart_module.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py", line 56, in smart_cond
    return false_fn()
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 163, in replace_training_and_call
    return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 639, in __call__
    return self.wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 599, in wrapper
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 165, in wrap_with_training_arg
    return control_flow_util.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/control_flow_util.py", line 109, in smart_cond
    return smart_module.smart_cond(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/smart_cond.py", line 56, in smart_cond
    return false_fn()
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    lambda: replace_training_and_call(False))
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/utils.py", line 163, in replace_training_and_call
    return wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 663, in call_and_return_conditional_losses
    call_output = layer_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "example.py", line 27, in call
    h = matmul(inputs, self.kernel) + constants[0]
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1250, in binary_op_wrapper
    raise e
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1234, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1565, in _add_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.add_v2(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 532, in add_v2
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 748, in _apply_op_helper
    op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 599, in _create_op_internal
    return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3557, in _create_op_internal
    ret = Operation(
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2041, in __init__
    self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
  File "/home/itamarst/Devel/tensorflow/venv/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1883, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 32 and 5 for '{{node add}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT](MatMul, constants)' with input shapes: [?,32], [?,?,5].
```

Any idea what's going on? Original code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48213

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by attaching

> .h5 extension in TF 2.6

in while saving model file

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.linalg import matmul
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

class MinimalRNNCell(tfk.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, states=None, constants=None, *args, **kwargs):
        prev_output = states[0]
        print("constants: ", constants[0].name)
        h = matmul(inputs, self.kernel) + constants[0]
        output = h + matmul(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]

    def get_config(self):
        return dict(super().get_config(), **{'units': self.units})

cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
x = tfk.Input((None, 5), name='x')
z = tfk.Input((1,), name='z')
layer = tfk.layers.RNN(cell, name='rnn')
y = layer(x, constants=[z])

model = tfk.Model(inputs=[x, z], outputs=[y])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.predict([np.array([[[0,0,0,0,0]]]), np.array([[0]])])
model.save('tmp.model.h5')
```